# Error while importing numpy: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I run the following code on my PC just fine but when I run it on my raspberry pi 3, It can not be found.

My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

cap.set(3,640) # set Width
cap.set(4,480) # set Height
while(True):enter code here
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        cv2.imshow('gray', gray)

        k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27: # press 'ESC' to quit
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

My error is :

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'`

Comment: `import numpy as np`

Comment: Please be specific - add the exact error to your question.

Comment: i am install the Numpy package but when import it i have these error

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'

Comment: First you need to install bumpy. Then you need to import it. Try pip install numpy
Import numpy as np

Comment: We're going to need far more information than this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to install `numpy` via `pip`

If you already have pip you should just be able to install it via

`pip install numpy`

or

`pip3 install numpy`

If you do not have pip, take a look on how to get it here:

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/